# Is there any possible way to check the particular scheduled job in crontab is running or not on scheduled time

Tags: linux, cron

```
 * * * * * bash shutdown.sh <input.sh
```

I want to check the particular scheduled job in crontab is running or not. Is this possible in Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what flavor of Linux you are running, here are my best suggestions. Assuming you used `crontab -e` to setup your job, it will log by default to the system log, or a specific cron log.  That could be `/var/log/syslog` or simply `/var/log/cron` depending on the Linux distro you are using.

You can try to search these logs with the `grep` command.

e.g.
`grep CRON /var/log/syslog` or if your system has a log at /var/log/cron, you can search the specific command in that log using `grep "bash shutdown.sh" /var/log/cron`

Another way is to explicitly call out where to log the job using some extra logic on your crontab entry:

`* * * * * bash shutdown.sh <input.sh > /tmp/shutdown.log`

Note, if you set up the job to log to a specific file/path, the file/path must exist and the user that the cron job is running as must have permissions to access/modify the file.